# Angular 4 + Material Design - removable chips

Tags: angularjs, angular, material-design

I need removable chips like above:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips

But I have to write it in Angular 4. How can I redo these chips https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview to removable?

Now I have to bind it to textarea like this:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="myChips">Chips:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" type="text" id="myChips" [(ngModel)]="myChips" name="myChips" placeholder="Write chips here"></textarea> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

How can I bind these chips as in the example from angularjs.org?

Comment: Use an array to store the strings for chips, render them with a ngfor loop, on click on a chip's cross icon, remove them from the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First import `font-awesome` to your project or have a `close` icon available (I used font-awesome for my example).

Then you can add the `icon` in the chip and add a `click` event to it. When the `close` icon is clicked pass the index of it and remove it from it's origin.

Example html:

```
<md-chip-list>
  <md-chip *ngFor="let chip of chips; let i = index"  
           color="accent">
    {{chip}}
    <i class="fa fa-close" (click)="remove(i)"></i>
  </md-chip>
</md-chip-list>
```

component.ts:

```
chips = [
 'Apple',
 'Orange',
 'Banana',
 'Mango',
 'Cherry'
]

remove(item){
  this.chips.splice(item, 1);
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/3ETqil1nCNc0iorge5El?p=preview)

Comment: Below I paste screenshot what I get. But I ddidn't achive the result.

Comment: Like I said, either you have to use an icon that you have in your local `assets > img` folder, or to use `font-awesome`, add this link in your index.html:  `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: I edit my question because I really need input with chips functionality. It can be input or text area.

Comment: It's better if you create a new question, since binding input/textarea with 
 `md-chip` is completely different then just having removable chip.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200931/angular-4-material-design-chips-in-input
I created new question here. If you know how to do that please tell me.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this [https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/chips][Chips]

This library compliments angular material perfectly.